# how to loop through multiple dataframes and write into multiple sheets of excel in R?

Tags: r, excel

i want to write into multiple sheets of excel using loop. code is mentioned below.

```
first_column <- c("value_1", "value_2")
second_column <- c("ve_1", "ve_2")

fir_column <- c("1", "2")
se_column <- c("a1", "va2")

df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column) #sheet A of df.xlsx
df1 <- data.frame(fir_column, se_column) #sheet B of df.xlsx

sheets<-openxlsx::getSheetNames('./Out/df.xlsx')

for(i in 1:length(sheets)){
  
  df<-read_excel('./Out/df.xlsx',sheet = sheets[i])
  
  write.xlsx(df, './Out/df1.xlsx', sheetName = i, append=TRUE)
}
```

Only last sheet is getting generated.

Comment: This works for me except `sheetName` has to be a character string (eg `as.character(i)`). It might be a good idea to add some logic to either remove the output excel workbook if it already exists (otherwise writing over will throw an error) or have `append = F` on the first iteration.

Comment: even after adding ```as.character(i)```  and removing append  only last sheet is getting generated

Comment: What is your package version of `xlsx`? As I mentioned this worked for me, but your code as posted should not run because `i` is numeric and `sheetName` must be character. So your posted code throws an error. Did you try clearing your environment before running this code?

Comment: ```xlsx package```  is throwing some javaerror so i'm using openxlsx - 4.2.3 . @LMc

Comment: The javaerror is because `i` is numeric or `df` is a `tibble`. Try using `xlsx::write.xlsx` with the argument `sheetName = as.character(i)`. Also, `read_excel` returns a `tibble`. So if you still get an error using `xlsx` try `as.data.frame(df)`. `openxlsx::write.xlsx` does not have an `append` argument and has a different syntax for writing multiple sheets.

Comment: `writexl` will take a list. `writexl::write_xlsx(list(sheet_name1 = df1, sheet_name2 = df2), path)` should do the trick. The name of the list item becomes the sheet name.

Comment: ```Error in .jcheck(silent = FALSE) : 
  Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "createCell", as.integer(colIndex[ic] - 1))new("jobjRef", jobj = <pointer: 0x00000246fca19790>, jclass = "java/lang/Throwable")``` this is ther error i'm getting for ``` xlsx::write.xlsx()``` @LMc

Comment: Did you wrap `df` with `as.data.frame` as previously mentioned: `xlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df),...)`?

Comment: yes ,```xlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df),...)```  same way i have done @LMc

Comment: Do any of my posted answers work? Both run for me. The first uses `xlsx` and the second `openxlsx`.

Comment: with ```openxlsx ``` worked . Thank You @LMc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code (note pathnames are edited slightly):

```
library(xlsx)
library(readxl)

sheets<-openxlsx::getSheetNames('./df.xlsx')

for(i in 1:length(sheets)){
  
  df<-readxl::read_excel('./df.xlsx',sheet = sheets[i])
  
  appendSheet <- i > 1
  
  # depending on version might need to do as.data.frame(df)
  xlsx::write.xlsx(df, './df1.xlsx', sheetName = as.character(i), append=appendSheet)
}
```

Or with `openxlsx`:

```
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)

sheets<-openxlsx::getSheetNames('./df.xlsx')

wb <- createWorkbook()

for(i in 1:length(sheets)){
  
  df<-readxl::read_excel('./df.xlsx',sheet = sheets[i])
  
  addWorksheet(wb, i)
  writeData(wb, i, df)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "df1.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

---

Alternatively, you can work with the sheets as list elements, allowing you to easily work over each element with the apply family of functions:

```
library(rio)
library(writexl)

list_of_dfs <- import_list("df.xlsx") # from rio
write_xlsx(list_of_dfs, "df1.xlsx") # from writexl
```